# how to add multiple ways to filter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am making an event application and so far the user can search by name of the event but I also want the user to be able to search by the name of the host and the category of the event. How can I achieve this in the same function?

```
handleSearch = query => {
    this.setState({ searchQuery: query });
    this.getPagedData();
  };

  getPagedData = () => {
    const { searchQuery, events: allEvents } = this.state;

    let filtered = allEvents;
    if (searchQuery) {
      filtered = allEvents.filter(e =>
        e.title.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchQuery.toLowerCase())
      );
    } 

    if (searchQuery.length === 0 || searchQuery.length === 1) {
      this.setState({
        events: getEvents()
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        events: filtered
      });
    }

    return { totalCount: filtered.length };
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create object with parameters and merge new into:

```
handleSearch = query => {
  this.setState({
    searchQuery: Object.assign(this.state.searchQuery, query)
  });
  this.getPagedData();
};
```

Then use [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) for serialize object into query string and make request with this string.